# AWK get last word first line , then copy and add one (inc) next line

Tags: awk

my goal is to : ADD + 1 to the last word WORD ($9) to the next line, thank you.

File INPUT before processing

```
U;1440564493023;17600000000057;AAA7;MICHEL;DUPONT;31/12/2050;SDIS;48813
U;1510832013115;17600000000924;AAA7;CEDRIC;FERNAND;31/12/2050;SDIS;2
U;1410832013785;17600000000081;AAA7;ERIC;FILOU;31/12/2050;SDIS;2
```

Desire File OUTPOUT after processing

```
U;1440564493023;17600000000057;AAA7;MICHEL;DUPONT;31/12/2050;SDIS;48813
U;1510832013115;17600000000924;AAA7;CEDRIC;FERNAND;31/12/2050;SDIS;48814
U;1410832013785;17600000000081;AAA7;ERIC;FILOU;31/12/2050;SDIS;48815

*
```

Comment: What distinguishes final fields you care about and final fields you don't? That is when do you grab the final value as opposed to using the last line's value plus one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$ awk -F";" 'NR==1{count = $9} {$9=count++}1 ' OFS=";"
```

**OR**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==1{count = $NF} {$NF=count++}1' input
```

---

**Test**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==1{count = $NF} {$NF=count++}1' input
U;1440564493023;17600000000057;AAA7;MICHEL;DUPONT;31/12/2050;SDIS;48813
U;1510832013115;17600000000924;AAA7;CEDRIC;FERNAND;31/12/2050;SDIS;48814
U;1410832013785;17600000000081;AAA7;ERIC;FILOU;31/12/2050;SDIS;48815
```

---

**What it does?**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` Sets the input and output field seprators as `;`
- `NR==1{count = $NF}` If the current record is the first record(where `NR` is `1`) sets the count variable as the last field value, `$NF`
- `{$NF=count++}` sets the last field as `count`. Increments value by `1`
- `1` Always true. Takes default action to print entire record.

Comment: Using `$NF` might be better assuming the real goal is the last word and not necessarily the ninth field.

Comment: Wonderfull ! works perfectly! Best wishes from France,  Etan.

Comment: @Zlorg glad to know it helped. You could accept the answer if you think its the right answer

Comment: @EtanReisner i'm on stack for few time (one day) , i don't kwown how to close the question and vote. I'll be check the 'how to'  to do that and accept after your answer in a while. thank's for your forbearance.

Comment: @Zlorg Welcome to stack Overflow !!!. Take a [tour on basics](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also to know more about [accepting answers and upvoting them](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)